# Mesh inside Plot legend

Tags: plotting, legending

I have a plot for which I would like to create an legend that is black and white printer friendly. I have seen Jen's legendmaker but I don't know how to adapt it. I need help in making the legend for the exit region to appear meshed. The graph is incomplete right now and I will add more stuff to it.. like J and V etc etc but for now I want the exit regions and their legends to be black and white printer friendly. What can I do to get a mesh to appear in the legend for the exit region. Thanks

**EDIT: Gaps in code fixed.**

[image]

```
I1 = 15;
I2 = 8;
f1[x_] := I1;
f2[x_] := I2;
hddd = 20;
h00d = 60;
h00s = 150;
hsss = 180;
    pl1 = Plot[{f1[x]}, {x, 0, 200}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
       PlotRange -> {-1, 20}, Epilog -> {
         Inset[
          Grid[{{Text[Style["J", "Garamond", 16]], 
             Text[Style["First Function", "Garamond", 16]]}, {Text[
              Style["V", "Garamond", 16]], 
             Text[Style["Second Function", "Garamond", 16]]}}], {h00s, 
           I1 + 3}],
         Inset[
          Grid[{{Item["", 
              Background -> RGBColor[0.35082, 0.595178, .853742], 
              Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1]], 
             Style["Continuation Region", "Garamond", 16]}, {Item["", 
              Background -> RGBColor[1, 1, .4], Frame -> True, 
              FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[1]], 
             Style["Exit Region", "Garamond", 16]}}]], Dashed, 
         Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{h00s, I1}, {h00s, 0}}], 
         Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{h00d, I1}, {h00d, 0}}], 
         Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{hddd, I1}, {hddd, 0}}], 
         Arrowheads[Small], Arrow[{{hsss, I2}, {hsss, 0}}], 
         Inset[Style["Down Boundaries", "Garamond", 
           16], {(hddd + h00d)/2, (I1 + I2)/2}],
         Inset[
          Style["Top Boundaries", "Garamond", 
           16], {(hsss + h00s)/2, (I1 + I2)/2}],
         }, Ticks -> {{{hddd, Text[Style["HDD", "Garamond", 20]]}, {h00d, 
           Text[Style["H0D", "Garamond", 20]]}, {h00s, 
           Text[Style["H0S", "Garamond", 20]]}, {hsss, 
           Text[Style["HSS", "Garamond", 20]]}}, {{I1, 
           Text[Style["High", "Garamond", 20]]}, {I2, 
           Text[Style["Low", "Garamond", 20]]}}}, 
       AxesLabel -> {Text[Style["Variable X", "Garamond", 20]], 
         Text[Style["Variable Y", "Garamond", 20]]}];
    pl2 = Plot[{f2[x]}, {x, 0, 200}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
       PlotRange -> {-1, 20}];
    ptd = ListPlot[{{h00d, I2}, {hddd, I1}}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}, 
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {-1, 20}];
    pts = ListPlot[{{h00s, I1}, {hsss, I2}}, 
       PlotStyle -> {Directive[Green, PointSize[Large]]}, 
       AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> {-1, 20}];
    r1 = RegionPlot[
       f1[x] > 0, {x, 0, hddd - 1}, {y, I1 - 0.15, I1 + 0.15}, 
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 1, .4], Mesh -> 2];
    r2 = RegionPlot[
       f1[x] > 0, {x, h00s + 1, 200}, {y, I1 - 0.15, I1 + 0.15}, 
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 1, .4], Mesh -> 2];
    r3 = RegionPlot[
       f1[x] > 0, {x, 0, h00d - 1}, {y, I2 - 0.15, I2 + 0.15}, 
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 1, .4], Mesh -> 2];
    r4 = RegionPlot[
       f1[x] > 0, {x, hsss + 1, 200}, {y, I2 - 0.15, I2 + 0.15}, 
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1, 1, .4], Mesh -> 2];
    r5 = RegionPlot[
       f1[x] > 0, {x, h00d + 1, hsss - 1}, {y, I2 - 0.1, I2 + 0.1}, 
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.35082, 0.595178, .853742]];
    r6 = RegionPlot[
       f1[x] > 0, {x, hddd + 1, h00s - 1}, {y, I1 - 0.1, I1 + 0.1}, 
       PlotStyle -> RGBColor[0.35082, 0.595178, .853742]];
    Show[pl1, pl2, ptd, pts, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**After Amatya's edit**

```
MeshMarker[a_, b_, col_: Lighter@Blue] :=RegionPlot[True, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
 Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> col, Mesh -> {a, b}, ImageSize -> 20]

SwatchLegend[{1, 2}, {"Continuation Region", "ExitRegion"},
LegendMarkerSize -> {{30,30}}, LegendMarkers -> MeshMarker @@@ {{2, 2, Yellow}, {0,0}}]
```

[image]

**Before Amatya's edit**

There are gaps in Your code so it does not work for me but look at following solutions.

**With `Mesh`**

```
MeshMarker[a_, b_] :=RegionPlot[True, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, Frame -> False, 
Mesh -> {a, b}, ImageSize -> 20];

Show[{
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> {0, 6}, 
 PlotLegends ->      SwatchLegend[{1}, {plot1}, LegendMarkers -> MeshMarker[0, 6], 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 30]],

 RegionPlot[(x - 5)^2 + y^2 < 4, {x, -3, 7}, {y, -3, 3}, Mesh -> {6, 0}, 
 PlotLegends ->     SwatchLegend[{1}, {plot2}, LegendMarkers -> MeshMarker[6, 0], 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 30]]

 }, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image]

**without `mesh`**

```
 texture = {
  Rasterize@Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}}]}, 
                     ImageSize -> 30, ImageMargins -> 0],
  Rasterize@Graphics[{Thick, Line[{{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{.5, 0}, {1, .5}}, {{0, .5}, {.5, 1}}}]},
                     ImageSize -> 30, ImageMargins -> 0, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
 };

Show[{
  RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 4, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
    PlotStyle -> Texture[texture[[1]]],TextureCoordinateScaling -> False,
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{1}, {"region 1"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 30}}, 
    LegendMarkers -> texture[[1]]]]
  ,  
  RegionPlot[(x - 5)^2 + y^2 < 4, {x, -3, 7}, {y, -3, 3},
    PlotStyle -> Texture[texture[[2]]], TextureCoordinateScaling -> False,
    PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend[{1}, {"region 2"}, LegendMarkerSize -> {{30, 30}},
    LegendMarkers -> texture[[2]]]]

  }, PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 500
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for the gaps in the code. I always get careless like this. I'll go over your code now.

Comment: @Amatya Don't worry :) it is not a big deal when question is clear.

Comment: I don't have MMA9 at school but I do have it at home so I will write back in 6-7 hours. Thanks.

Comment: @Amatya No problem, but in case of earlier version `MeshMarker` can be simply in a `Grid` like in Your code.

Comment: Sorry I vanished for two weeks. Thanks a lot for your solution!