# Making a rectangular label for RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling, filling

I have a plot that includes a `RegionPlot`. I want to make a rectangle with the same shading as in the region plot to show as a legend. The dumb way I can think off is to make another region plot over a small rectangular space and show that as a legend, but that does not seem like a great idea considering I might want to change the plots.

Any better suggestions?

For practice, I want to label the following example:

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {(2 #1 - #2) &, (2 #1 - #2) &}, Mesh -> 100]
```

<sub>*Keywords:* hatched filling, legend with hatched filling</sub>

Comment: Please see the answer here: [Mesh inside Plot legend](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26499)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps a "quick" appoach (in addition to looking at hyperlink of @rm-rf):

```
msp[f_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, mfun_, mnum_, swatchsize_, 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{pm, swl},
  pm = RegionPlot[x < 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> mfun, 
    Mesh -> IntegerPart@(mnum/(swatchsize/10)), Frame -> False, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[RegionPlot]], 
    ImageSize -> swatchsize];
  swl = SwatchLegend["Expressions", LegendMarkers -> pm, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> swatchsize];
  RegionPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
   MeshFunctions -> mfun, Mesh -> mnum, 
   Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[RegionPlot]], 
   PlotLegends -> swl]]
```

Some examples:

```
msp[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {#1 &, #2 &}, 50, 50]
```

[image]

```
msp[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {#1 + #2 &, #1 - #2 &}, 50, 50]
```

[image]

```
msp[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {#1 &, #2 &}, 50, 50, 
 PlotStyle -> Yellow, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Purple}]
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
mspmod[f_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, mfun_, mnum_, swatchsize_, 
  col_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{pm, swl}, 
  pm = RegionPlot[x < 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> mfun, 
      Mesh -> IntegerPart@(mnum/(swatchsize/10)), Frame -> False, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotStyle -> #, 
      Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[RegionPlot]], 
      ImageSize -> swatchsize] & /@ col;
  swl = SwatchLegend["Expressions", LegendMarkers -> pm, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> swatchsize];
  RegionPlot[f, {x, xmin, xmax}, {y, ymin, ymax}, 
   MeshFunctions -> mfun, Mesh -> mnum, PlotStyle -> col, 
   Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[RegionPlot]], 
   PlotLegends -> swl]]
```

Example:

```
mspmod[{x^3 - y^2 > 2, x^2 + y^3 > 3, 
  x^3 - y^2 > 2 && x^2 + y^3 > 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, 50, 50, {Red, 
  Green, Yellow}]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried to make improvements to make this valid for two functions, but the coloring of the legend is always just one of them. Any suggestions on how to make msp accept multiple functions? Worst case, I'll just use Show. Thanks!

Comment: @Lina , I suspect Show is simplest way. Will think about when I get time. Hyperlink already referred in other comments may give inspiration.

Comment: @Lina see update

Comment: @Lina for some reason the update I made disappeared so I reupdated.

Answer (score 4):

You can also create hatched images (say, `img`) using `ParametricPlot` and use them with  `PlotStyle -> Texture[img]` in `RegionPlot`:

Reusing the function `hatchF` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152558/125):

```
ClearAll[hatchF]
hatchF[mf_List: {# &, #2 &}, mesh_List: {50, 50}, 
  style_: GrayLevel[.5], opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> mesh, 
  MeshFunctions -> mf, MeshStyle -> style, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  opts, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, Axes -> False]

t1a = hatchF[{# - #2 &}, {60}, Red, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Yellow]];
t1b = hatchF[{# + #2 &}, {60}, Purple, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5, Cyan]];
t2a = hatchF[{# + #2 &}, {80}, None, MeshShading -> {None, Blue}];
t2b = hatchF[{# - #2 &}, {80}, None, MeshShading -> {Red, None}];
t3 = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
t4 = ImageCrop[ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Metal4"}], {600, 600}];
Grid[Transpose@Partition[{t1a, t1b, t2a, t2b, t3, t4}, 2]]
```

[image]

```
funcs = {Abs[x^3 - y^2] > 2, x^2 + y^3 < 1/2};
labels = Append[TraditionalForm /@ #, TraditionalForm[And @@ #]] & @ funcs;
markers = Append[ImageCrop[#, 30] & /@ {t1a, t1b}, ImageCrop[Show[t1a, t1b], 30]];
legend = Grid[Transpose[{markers, labels}], Alignment -> Left];

Legended[#, legend] &@
 RegionPlot[funcs, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Opacity[.5], Texture @ t1a}, {Opacity[.5], Texture @ t1b}}]
```

[image]

In versions 11.0+, use

```
  PlotStyle -> {Texture @ SetAlphaChannel[t1a, .5], Texture @ SetAlphaChannel[t1b, .5]}
```

Use `t2a` and `t2b` in places of `t1a` and `t1b` to get:

[image]

Use `t3` in place of `t2` and

```
 markers = Append[ImageCrop[#, 30] & /@ {t2a, ImageResize[t3, {50, 50}]}, 
   ImageCrop[Show[SetAlphaChannel[ImageResize[t3, {50, 50}], .9], 
     SetAlphaChannel[t2a, .3]], 30]];
```

to get

[image]

Replace `t3` with `t4` to get

[image]

Comment: I think this should now read "In version 11 and higher, use".

Answer (score 0):

In versions 12.1 and newer, we can use the new styling directives [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) and  [`PatternFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html):

```
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, HatchFilling[]], 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend["AllExpressions", LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 40}]]
```

[image]

```
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotStyle -> PatternFilling[{"Diamond", LightBlue, Blue}, ImageScaled[.03]], 
  PlotLegends -> SwatchLegend["AllExpressions", LegendMarkerSize -> {40, 40}]]
```

[image]